# Has anyone experienced conflicts with colortbl?

Tags: color, colortbl

I was just trying to insert a vertical line between columns in a table and I couldn't figure out why it never showed up in my output.  So I started from scratch with a minimal setup and added my packages one at a time to see which conflicted.  It turns out that colortbl was the culprit.  I've always had some issues with xcolor, but I thought colortbl was safer.

Here's a sample of the code (as minimal as I could get it)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage[ragged]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{booktabs,mathptmx,siunitx,tabto,listliketab}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape,longtable}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf,it},justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{array,color,xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{yellow}{RGB}{255 255 0}
\newlength{\maxcolorbox}
\settowidth{\maxcolorbox}{28.8}
\newcommand{\cbox}[2]{\colorbox{#1}{\parbox{\maxcolorbox}{\centering #2}}}
 \begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\scriptsize
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{ccccccc|cccccc}
         \toprule
                &\multicolumn{6}{c|}{DRP Executive}&\multicolumn{6}{c}{Optimized Smoothing Models}\\
 Part \#&Jan-17&Feb-17&Mar-17&Apr-17&May-17&Jun-17&Jan-17&Feb-17&Mar-17&Apr-17&May-17&Jun-17\\
         \midrule
200018373   &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}SS}  &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}SS}  &   SS  &   &   &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}SS}  &   DS  &   DS  &   SS  &   CR  &   SS  &   DS  \\
200019547   &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}MA}  &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}MA}  &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}CR}  &   &   &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}CR}  &   DS  &   DS  &   DS  &   SS  &   MA  &   DS  \\
200020385   &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}MA}  &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}MA}  &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}DS}  &   &   &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}MA}  &   DS  &   DS  &   CR  &   DS  &   CR  &   SS  \\
200023707   &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}MA}  &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}MA}  &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}MA}  &   &   &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}MA}  &   DS  &   SS  &   DS  &   DS  &   DS  &   CR  \\
200026052   &   DS  &   DS  &   DS  &   &   &   MA  &   DS  &   DS  &   DS  &   DS  &   CR  &   MA  \\
200028541   &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}MA}  &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}MA}  &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}DS}  &   &   &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}DS}  &   DS  &   DS  &   SS  &   MA  &   DS  &   CR  \\
200028623   &   DS  &   DS  &   DS  &   &   &   WA  &   DS  &   DS  &   DS  &   CR  &   CR  &   CR  \\
200030213   &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}SS}  &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}SS}  &   \cbox{yellow}{\color{black}SS}  &   &   &   WA  &   DS  &   CR  &   CR  &   CR  &   CR  &   DS  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us the packages you are loading that are conflicting. `xcolor` is really stable. It shouldn't cause conflicts. Also, `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` loads `colortbl`.

Comment: it might be pdf viewers artifact (to not show lines). to confirm this, we need to see small but complete document with your table.

Comment: vertical rules and colour don't go well together (some pdf viewers are better than others) xcolor and colortbl are the same thing here as xcolor just load colortbl for its table support

Comment: I've adderd a sample of my code above.  It only works if I remove colortbl

Comment: BTW: you have many redundant packages, for example there is no need to load `enumerate` when you are overwriting it right away with `enumitem`

Comment: BTW2: you should never use vertical lines with the booktabs rules anyway, that is the whole point of using the booktabks rules

Comment: The rules come back if I remove `arydshln`, what are you loading that for when you are using the booktabs rules?

Comment: Read the documentation of arydshln: it must be loader *after* colortbl and some more packages.

Comment: Thanks all.  I'm using booktabs to add the \toprule and \bottomrule in the table.  I only load packages when adding something requires that package.  I don't remove them, but usually just copy all the details to a new file when I need to write another report.

Comment: @Angus but booktabs explictly documents that by design it breaks vertical  rules, so don't load it if you have vertical rules. Also the example posted is _far_ from minimal, you should remove almost all the packages as they are unrelated to this question, and just make it much harder for anyone offering to help who may need to trace TeX's behaviour.

Comment: I agree about the minimal example, sorry about that.  I altered the table by just leaving anextra space between the two separate segments and by using \cmidrule where necessary.  It looks pretty good and may be a way to divorce myself from using vertical lines.